# Android phonegap crashes on landscape

Tags: java, android, cordova

My app has an embedded cordovaWebview which is running properly on portrait. However, when turn into landscape, app crashes reporting following errors.
Before posting, I had read a lot of entries about this problem that were solved adding |orientation to all activities on manifest. Done but not a solution! 
If more code is required please ask. Thank you.

```
01-31 20:34:57.797: E/AndroidRuntime(17868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 20:34:57.797: E/AndroidRuntime(17868): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 20:34:57.797: E/AndroidRuntime(17868):    at java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:1145)
01-31 20:34:57.797: E/AndroidRuntime(17868):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrlNow(CordovaWebView.java:499)
01-31 20:34:57.797: E/AndroidRuntime(17868):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrl(CordovaWebView.java:384)
01-31 20:34:57.797: E/AndroidRuntime(17868):    at com.nimbosolutions.projecte1.webPush.onConfigurationChanged(webPush.java:138)
01-31 20:34:57.797: E/AndroidRuntime(17868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:2962)
01-31 20:34:57.797: E/AndroidRuntime(17868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3052)
01-31 20:34:57.797: E/AndroidRuntime(17868):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1016)
```

Comment: It looks like your URL string is being wiped out when the orientation changes.  Where do you initialize the variable?

Comment: What do you have set for the configChanges of your main activity in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my own application and I add "screenSize" to android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml. Now, it looks like that :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Hope it helps...